# Could the uncertainty principle theoretically be violated at 0 K?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, temperature, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

Ok so please excuse me if the following mental argument is completely ridiculous or obviously flawed :P 
I was reading about how, even at 0 K (assuming we could experimentally reach such a temperature), there must be some slight particulate motion, because of the uncertainty principle. What about if we have some particles in a closed box that is in a dark vacuum (assuming a complete absence of any energy or light). If we then proceed to cool the particles to 0 K, then wouldn't we have succeeded at violating the uncertainty principle? We know that the speed of the particles is exactly 0 m/s, and we know with 100% certainty that they are in the box; we do not need to observe them to know so.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Absolute zero and Heisenberg uncertainty principle](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/56170/)

Comment: you should check the answers to the question linked above^ @marm_96

Comment: Absolute Zero represents a minimum amount of thermal energy, but it does NOT correspond to zero atomic motion.

Comment: Ok, for argument's sake, let's say it did correspond to zero atomic motion; then would the uncertainty principle be violated? Maybe the uncertainty principle only holds when there is a minimum particle motion?

Comment: The uncertainty principle holds for any quantum system. There are as many ways to avoid it as there are to avoid the second law of thermodynamics.

Comment: No, for example, removing energy from ('cooling') a quantum harmonic oscillator until it is in the minimum energy (ground) state means that no further energy can be extracted from the system - it is as 'cold' as it can get.  The system has minimum energy and the state saturates the lower bound of uncertainty.

Comment: How could a physically **impossible** situation violate a principle? The inaccessibility of $T=0K$ is already in classical thermodynamics.

Answer (score 0):

You say that the particle is closed in the box. By the time you limit the linear dimensions of the particle, you ***already*** fall under the reign of the uncertainty principle. If the box is, for simplicity, a cube of linear dimension $L$,

$\Delta p_i \ge \hbar/L$, where $i$ stands for $x, y, z$.

From now on, you have no control on $p_x, p_y$, and $p_z$ ? You can cool the box, so what?

You say "*We know that the speed of the particles is exactly* 0 *m/s,*". No, you don't know.