# Is everything solid at 0 K?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, temperature, phase-transition, states-of-matter

**Are there any materials that are not solid at 0 K?**

When thinking of the internal energy of a system of particles, I suppose the system will simply converge to the closest minimum of potential of the configurational energy, and then not change its configuration once it is there. Is that true? Also, are there real systems with a perfectly flat potential in regard with some degrees of freedom that would allow the configuration to change?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Absolute zero and Heisenberg uncertainty principle](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/56170/)

Comment: @JohnRennie I'm afraid you'll have to explain how that is a duplicate of this question, since this one doesn't mention the HUP at all. That your answer there is broad enough to also answer this question doesn't mean the questions are duplicates.

Answer (score 6):

Yes. Helium does not become solid at 0K. The idea that "the system will simply converge to the closest minimum of potential" has not taken into account the quantum effect. Even if the potential is not flat, the atoms will still not stay at rest at the potential minimal due to quantum fluctuations, which is always present even at 0K. The atoms can tunnel from one potential minimal to another in quantum mechanics. If the tunneling is strong enough, solid can be melt by quantum fluctuations, and the system will become a superfluid. Indeed that is the reason that Helium remains in a superfluid state at 0K and does not solidify.

Comment: it depends on boundaries conditions then?

Comment: Nice answer! Besides quantum fluctuations, if you have any idea of real systems with flat potentials, could you mention them? Thanks.

Comment: @Tony I can not imagine any real system to have perfectly flat potential, because **perfect is not real**.